# How can I remove duplicate strings from an array and count them in Swift?

Tags: arrays, count, swift5

want to print out duplicate characters first and the next number of characters.

like from ["a","a","b","c","c"] to ["a", "2","c","2"].

However, I properly didn't solve this. want you to give me feedback on my code or let me know your wisdom how can you solve this.

```
import Foundation

var m : [String] = ["a","a","b","c","c"]

var count : Int = 0

var result : [String] = []

for i in 0..<m.count{
for word in m {

    if m[i] == word{
        count += 1
        result.append(word)

    }else{
        count = 0
    }
    if count > 1{
       result.append(String(count))
    }
}
}

print("\(count)")
print("\(result)") 
//["a", "a", "2", "a", "a", "2", "b", "c", "c", "2", "c", "c", "2"]


print(["a", "2","c","2"])// want to print it on the console like this.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a type for it, [`NSCountedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscountedset)

```
let m = ["a","a","b","c","c"]

let countedSet = NSCountedSet(array: m)
var result = [String]()
countedSet.forEach {
   let count = countedSet.count(for: $0)
   if count > 1 {
       result.append(contentsOf: [$0 as! String, String(count)])
   }
}
print(result)
```

Comment: was curious about one things when I saw your code. let me know why you use as! instead as?

Comment: `NSCountedSet` – as many Objective-C derived types – doesn't care about types, in terms of Swift the elements are `Any`. The forced cast is harmless because you  **know** that the array contains only strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can get directly get duplicate value by below method

```
let fiteredValue = arrayList.filterDuplicates(includeElement: {$0 == $1})
```